# Personal quiz with input validation

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, quiz

The object of the code is to prompt the user with a quiz and collect the g's, y's, 0's, and 1's and if there is more than one then the user passes (else, they fail).  I am a beginner and would like to know if there is a more efficient direction for this code to go in.

```
from time import sleep
print(pic1)


def check(name):
    if name.lower() == "brandon":
        print("Welcome home master")
    else:
        print("Let's find some data")
        sleep(0.5)
        print("What is your favorite color?")
        color = input("fav_color>>> ")
        if color == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("What is your dream car?")
        car = input("fav_car>>> ")
        if car == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("What team are you on?")
        team = input("team_name>>> ")
        if team == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("Who is your best friend?")
        crush = input("best_friend>>> ")
        if crush == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("What color is your shirt?")
        shirt = input("shirt_color>>> ")
        if shirt == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("You got clout?")
        clout = input("clout_level>>> ")
        if clout == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("Do you think you passed the test?")
        passed = input("passed?>>> ")
        if passed == "":
            print("No skipping!")
            print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
        print("Calculating...")
        sleep(2.5)

        def add():
            color_counted = color.count("g")
            car_counted = car.count("g")
            team_counted = team.count("g")
            crush_counted = crush.count("g")
            shirt_counted = shirt.count("g")
            clout_counted = clout.count("y")
            clout_counted2 = clout.count("1")
            clout_counted3 = clout.count("0")
            passed_counted = passed.count("y")
            total = color_counted + car_counted + team_counted + clout_counted3 + passed_counted
            total = crush_counted + shirt_counted + clout_counted + clout_counted2
            return total
        if add() > 1:
            print("passed")
        else:
            print("failed")
        print("Congrats on your result!")
        sleep(100)


check(input("Enter Name Here>>> "))
```

Comment: also do not mind the print(pic1) at the beginning of the code, it was something I was messing around with and forgot to delete.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I made the title a bit more descriptive of the code. From  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". If there is a more appropriate description then feel free to update it via [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview! This isn't great code, but that doesn't mean that this is a bad question. I think that you've come to the right place.

### Recursion

```
    if color == "":
        print("No skipping!")
        print(check(input("Enter Name Here>>> ")))
```

This uses recursion when it shouldn't. In other words, `check` is calling itself needlessly, and if the user tries to "skip" enough times, you'll get a stack overflow. Instead of doing this, just loop until you have valid input.

### Fake delays

```
    print("Calculating...")
    sleep(2.5)
```

Few things bother me more than when a user interface lies to me. This output suggests that it takes 2.5 seconds for a calculation to be done, but that simply isn't so. Don't lie to your users - just show the results.

`sleep(100)` is actively harmful - the user needs to Ctrl+C to kill the program; otherwise it sits there preventing the user from getting their shell terminal back. This should just be deleted.

### Don't repeat yourself

There are many places in the program that are expressed in a repetitive manner, especially user input (the "no skipping" mechanism), the call to `count`, and the additions to get `total`. I suggest the following:

```
def input_without_skip(prompt: str) -> str:
    while True:
        result = input(f'{prompt}>>>')
        if result:
            return result
        print('No skipping!')


def is_master() -> bool:
    return input_without_skip('Enter Name Here') == 'Hercules'


def get_counts():
    for question, prompt, chars in (
        (     'What is your favorite color?',   'fav_color', 'g'),
        (          'What is your dream car?',     'fav_car', 'g'),
        (            'What team are you on?',   'team_name', 'g'),
        (         'Who is your best friend?', 'best_friend', 'g'),
        (        'What color is your shirt?', 'shirt_color', 'g'),
        (                   'You got clout?', 'clout_level', 'y10'),
        ('Do you think you passed the test?',     'passed?', 'y')
    ):
        print(question)
        answer = input_without_skip(prompt)
        yield sum(answer.count(c) for c in chars)


def main():
    if is_master():
        print('Welcome home, master.')
        return

    print("Let's find some data!")
    total = sum(get_counts())

    if total > 1:
        print("passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
    print("Congrats on your result!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks great content the only reason I put sleep 100 is because I am converting this program into an .exe and it stops running as soon as showing the result without giving the user time to read it.

Comment: The solution is not to sleep, it's too change the way that you execute the program. Either execute it from a command window, or change the properties of your shortcut.

Comment: Alright, and also since I am just getting into Python what is with the -> str while defining a function? Sorry to bother, but I just have some questions of the code you suggested.

Comment: Those are PEP484 type hints. That one says that the function returns a string.

Comment: Alright so it is not necessary but helpful?

Comment: Right! Think of it like a comment.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have to go now but I have more questions I will ask later, that ok?

Comment: Alright so in general your response is a lot more advanced than my knowledge of Python and I hope to learn more about this as I progress, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @pythonier500 You're welcome. Yes, you can ask questions later, but please do it in this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98513/personal-quiz-with-input-validation rather than in the comments.

Comment: I would, the only problem is I do not have enough reputation to use a chat room